# Does this code defer retrieval of the event logs until they've been queried?

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, event-log

Where `log` is an object of type `EventLog`, does this code...

`log.Entries.Cast<EventLogEntry>().Where(x => x.TimeGenerated == myDate).ToList();`

...somehow query (my `Where` lambda) prior to retrieving all of the logs so that it performs better? (Similarly to how EF would with a DB query) Or does it first pull the entire log into memory and filter from there?

If the latter, is it 'best' (i.e. fast, and more 'performant') to use [this approach](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb671200(v=vs.90).aspx#Y0) instead (i.e. pass in the XML and let the query do the lifting)?

I may have worded this a little awkwardly, I'm basically asking if the first approach I mentioned is inefficient for querying.

Comment: `ToList()` forces a full load. If you want to defer retrieval just remove `ToList()`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - Yes but prior to that I'd specified a query. In EF `.ToList().Where...` would be a terrible idea, `.Where().ToList()...` not so much. Is this not similar?

Comment: Not at all. An IEnumerable only retrieves values as requested. You get a performance benefit due to the lazy iteration.. `ToList()` retrieves *all* of them and adds them to a list. You'd still have to read all events, but you want' have to wait for all of them to arrive before iterating over them.

Comment: You need a LINQ provider that targets EventLog and translates LINQ statements to the XML query language. Or you can create a view in Event Viewer and [copy its XML definition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9129941/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-query-event-logs-for-message-contents-in-c)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - thanks a lot! That clears it up. Appreciate your response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it does not perform any better, because log.Entries implement simple `IEnumerable`, not something like `IQueryable` (like EF does for example). It means it does not analyze your "Where" clause expression tree and does not convert it somehow to event query before enumeration. So your query is roughly the same as:

```
var result = new List<EventLogEntry>();
foreach (EventLogEntry x in log.Entries) {
    if (x.TimeGenerated == myDate) {
        result.Add(x);
    }
}
return result;
```

Comment: Brilliant, concise answer Evk! Exactly what I was after. Thank you.